# update target table based on data source table if empty

Tags: mysql

Possibly a duplicate been searching for the specific answer i need but couldnt find it. I have two simple tables

```
Source :
    | Id | companyName | adress  |
    |----|-------------|---------|
    |  1 | aquatics    | street1 |
    |  2 | rivers      | street2 |

target :
    | Id | nameCompany | companyAdress  |
    |----|-------------|----------------|
    |  1 | aquatics    | street1        |
    |  2 | rivers      |                |
```

I simplified the matter, I have two sets of data the source table is extern data en i as a dev want to update my table with the extern data.

So we see that in the source everything is filled in.
I miss some info. In this case i miss the adress.

How can i run a query that checks: your row is incomplete. Lemme update this target row with the source data.

Only problem is. Extern data uses a different name voor the same columns as i have.

Been a couple of days with mysql. So pls try to explain noob friendly tried some thing but i couldnt figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below query updates `companyAdress` on `target` table if `adress` column on `Source` table is not equal to `companyAdress` on `target` table.

If you only need to update the empty values for `target.companyAdress` you should change the condition `where s.adress <> t.companyAdress`  to `where t.companyAdress =''`

```
update target t
inner join `Source` s
on t.nameCompany=s.companyName
set t.companyAdress=s.adress
where s.adress <> t.companyAdress ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pB6b5xrgPKCivFWcpQHsyE/0

Comment: Thank you! Easy to follow explanation, and if the rows had more data like a postal code and house number. if those field were also empty in the target. i could use  a komma in the SET to specify wich fields to update based on your explanation then the WHERE needs to be updated right? how would i do that

Comment: @ThazArrows yes. Just add like `set t.companyAdress=s.adress , t.postal_code=s.postal_code` so on

Comment: Hahha yes that i understand but now i have a problem in wich the only rows that are affected are those with a empty adress. so the where also needs to change to if any column in the row is empty update that row with the data wich we set in the SET parameters

Comment: @ThazArrows yes that is correct because you have the where condition `s.adress <> t.companyAdress` you have to add the other condition as well. `where s.adress <> t.companyAdress  and s.postal_code<>t.postal_code`

Comment: Oke so now i'm trying a little thing different. I don't want to update it anymore on condition <> but on if value blank than update. I also tried to add a third table but i am clueless. So let's say the source table has a extra column named worker_id. The target is two tables that needs to be updated now because i have a worker table